# How to read SSL certificate from windows certificate store using Delphi

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, indy

I am implementing a Delphi Windows Service as a server and wants to enable TLS/SSL for secure communication. for this I have used `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` component and I am able to set up secure communication between client and server.

My question is related to how I have loaded the certificate and key. I have written below code to load certificate and key file :

```
  IOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'localhost.cert.pem';    // Certificate file
  IOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'localhost.key.pem';      // Key File    
  IOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'ca.cert.pem';       // Root certificate
```

All the files (cert and key) are placed in the application directory. But one of the requirement is to read certificates from Windows certificate store.

How could I read certificate from Windows certificate store inside Delphi code and assign those certificates to `IOHandler.SSLOptions`?

Comment: OpenSSL (and by extension, Indy) does not support loading certificates from the Windnows certificate store, so you will have to export the desired certificate(s) to file(s) first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinCrypt functions to export choosen certificate and its chain to a PFX file, then assign that file path to CertFile, KeyFile and RootCertFile properties (yes, you can use the same file if it contains all the certificates).

The certificate must have the "export" flag.

Next example is tested in Delphi 2010 and make use of [JwaWinCrypt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) unit:

```
// Some declarations missing in JwaWinCrypt
function PFXExportCertStoreEx(hStore: HCERTSTORE;
                              var pPFX: CRYPT_DATA_BLOB;
                              szPassword: LPCWSTR;
                              pvPra: Pointer;
                              dwFlags: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Crypt32.dll';

const
  REPORT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY                 = $0001;
  REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY = $0002;
  EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS                   = $0004;
  PKCS12_INCLUDE_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES    = $0010;

  // Password to protect PFX file
  WidePass: WideString = ''; 


var
  pStore, pStoreTmp: HCERTSTORE;
  pCert: PCERT_CONTEXT;
  PFX,
  Hash: CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB;

  ChainPara: CERT_CHAIN_PARA;
  EnhkeyUsage: CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE;
  CertUsage: CERT_USAGE_MATCH;
  pChainContext: PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT;
  ppCertSimpleChain: ^PCERT_SIMPLE_CHAIN;
  ppCertChainElement: ^PCERT_CHAIN_ELEMENT;

  i, j: Integer;
  Buffer: RawByteString;

begin
  pStore := nil;
  pStoreTmp := nil;
  pCert := nil;

  PFX.pbData := nil;
  PFX.cbData := 0;

  // Open system certificate store
  pStore := CertOpenSystemStore(0, 'MY');

  // Open in-mem temporal certificate store
  pStoreTmp := CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY, 0, 0, 0, nil);

  // HEX SHA1 Hash of the certificate to find
  Buffer := 'YourCertificateSHA1HashHEX9be0c6fef0600b';
  Hash.cbData := Length(Buffer);
  Hash.pbData := @Buffer[1];
  // Find it
  pCert := CertFindCertificateInStore(pStore,
                                      X509_ASN_ENCODING,
                                      0,
                                      CERT_FIND_SHA1_HASH,
                                      @Hash,
                                      nil);

  // Now let's get the certificate's chain context
  EnhkeyUsage.cUsageIdentifier := 0;
  EnhkeyUsage.rgpszUsageIdentifier := nil;
  CertUsage.dwType := USAGE_MATCH_TYPE_AND;
  CertUsage.Usage := EnhkeyUsage;
  ChainPara.cbSize := SizeOf(CERT_CHAIN_PARA);
  ChainPara.RequestedUsage := CertUsage;

  CertGetCertificateChain(0, pCert, nil, nil, 
                          @ChainPara, 0, nil, @pChainContext);

  // Iterate the chain context and add every certificate to mem-store
  ppCertSimpleChain := Pointer(pChainContext^.rgpChain);
  for i := 1 to pChainContext.cChain do
  begin
    ppCertChainElement := Pointer(ppCertSimplechain^.rgpElement);
    for j := 1 to ppCertSimpleChain^.cElement do
    begin
      CertAddCertificateLinkToStore(pStoreTmp,
                                    ppCertChainElement^.pCertContext,
                                    CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING,
                                    nil);
      Inc(ppCertChainElement);
    end;
    Inc(ppCertSimpleChain);
  end;

  // Save to PFX ...
  PFX.pbData := nil;
  PFX.cbData := 0;
  // First a call with an empty BLOB to get the space needed
  PFXExportCertStoreEx(pStoreTmp, 
                       PFX, 
                       PWideChar(WidePass), 
                       nil, 
                       EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS + 
                       REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY + 
                       REPORT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY + 
                       PKCS12_INCLUDE_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);

  // OK, reserve the needed memory
  GetMem(PFX.pbData, PFX.cbData);

  // Fill data
  PFXExportCertStoreEx(pStoreTmp, 
                       PFX, 
                       PWideChar(WidePass), 
                       nil, 
                       EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS + 
                       REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY + 
                       REPORT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY + 
                       PKCS12_INCLUDE_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);

  // Now PFX.pbData points to PFX information of length PFX.cbData
  // Write it to a temporary file that replaces your PEM files.

  // Free memory used
  // I deliberately did not check whether 
  // previous API calls returned an error.
  // You should check.
  // Take a look to Microsoft's documentation for functions results
  // and GetLastError function for error code
  CertFreeCertificateChain(pChainContext);
  CertFreeCertificateContext(pCert);
  CertCloseStore(pStoreTmp, 0);
  CertCloseStore(pStore, 0);
  FreeMem(PFX.pbData);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delphi DLL CHILKAT.

https://www.example-code.com/delphidll/cert_load_from_windows_cert_store.asp

Cert Delphi DLL Reference Documentation:

https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/dd_CkCertRef.html

Comment: have you used it in your project ?

Comment: I keep the certificates in the database. This is convenient because I can access the certificate from any computer and the certificates do not need to be imported into the windows cert store.